On the relationship between $\Delta|\nabla u|$ and scalar curvature
I'm working on a Riemannian Geometry problem.
I need to prove the following formula:
$$
\Delta |\nabla f| = \frac{1}{2} \frac{|\nabla \nabla f|^2}{|\nabla f|} + \frac{1}{2} |\nabla f| (R^M - R^\Sigma).
$$
where f is a smooth function over my Riemannian manifold $(M^3,g)$, $\Delta f=0$ on $M$, $\Delta f \neq 0$ on M, $R^\Sigma (p)$ is the scalar curvature of the metric induced by $g$ on the level set $\{f=f(p)\}$.
I'm literally going insane. I know that somehow I need to use Bochner's formula with the harmonicity of $f$ but I'm not able to obtain $\Delta |\nabla f|$ from $\Delta |\nabla f|^2$! 
I'm starting to doubt that the formula is not even correct...you're my last hope! Any help will be incredibly appreciated. 
Thank you!
